# Prove that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega = [0,1]$, then $\{x\} \in \mathcal{B}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm studying sigma algebras and I don't understand a proof I found for this question. Briefly, what was done is:

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $[0,1]$ and we have $A_1, A_2, \ldots \in \mathcal{B}$, we know that $\displaystyle \bigcap_ {n = 1}^{\infty}A_n \in \mathcal{B}$. So the goal is to write $\{x\} = \displaystyle \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n$ to show that $\{x\} \in \mathcal{B}$.

We take $A_n = \left[x,x + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)$, for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ and get the result
$$\{x\} = \bigcap_ {n=1}^{\infty}\left[x,x + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \Longrightarrow \{x\} \in \mathcal{B}.$$

The problem for me is that $\Omega = [0,1]$ and for many values of $n$ we have $\left[x,x + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \nsubseteq \Omega$ .

I would like to know is there anything I missed at this point.

Comment: But what value is $x$?

Comment: $0 \leq x \leq 1$. For example, if $x = 0.5$ and $n=1$ we have $[0.5, 1.5)$

Comment: If $x<1$ then just go for $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty}A_n$ with $m$ large enough (i.e. $x+\frac1m\in\Omega$). Also you could take $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$ where $B_n=A_n\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: Taking $n =m$ large enough is what I was thinking, but my doubt is that in more than one place the proofs start in $n=1$, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Your use of the indefinite pronoun "a", in the phrase "a Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $[0,1]$", is peculiar. It invites the thought that there is more than one Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $[0,1]$, whereas in fact any topological space has just one Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: For $x=1$ you can go for $\{1\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac1n,1]$. Actually things are more simple. For that see my answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher "A" is actually the indefinite _article_, not a pronoun...

Comment: Indeed, a typographical error on my part. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira Please check my edit of your question.

Comment: Thank you @drhab! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\mathcal B$ is the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$) then $\tau\subseteq\mathcal B$.

This means that $\mathcal B$ contains all open sets, but also - because $\mathcal B$ is closed under complementation - contains all closed sets.

So $\mathcal B$ contains all singletons if every singleton is closed or open.

In the case you are working on all singletons are closed.